# How can I make a userscript that changes every 'href' attribute of every element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, userscripts

I have seen a similar question, but it gets the href attribute of every class, I want the href attribute of every single element. Then I want to change it to one link that I specify.Their solution looked like this:

```
var a,b,c,d, len;

a = document.getElementsByClassName("item title_link");
len = a.length;

    b = a[i].getAttribute('href');
    c = b.replace("#", "");
    d = "http://www.domainname.com/index/" + c + "/get";
    console.log(d); //just to check them out
}

//window.location.href = d;
//or whatever you wanted to do with that...
```

Any way to make this replace every attribute instead of only the specified class?

Comment: is `getElementsByTagName()` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you added the jQuery tag, I assume that you accept an answer that uses jQuery. Using it it's extremely simple, you just have to do this:

```
$("[href]").attr("href", "your desired href destination");
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nbLhaker/) is a jsfiddle with an example.

**Explaination**: the `[href]` selector selects all elements with an attribute called `href`, and the `.attr()` function replaces its value for your desired value.

Comment: Thanks! so easy and efficient!

Comment: Actually jQuery is a bit less efficient than built-in functions, but I think the readability is worth losing a tiny bit of performance.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Javascript way:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
[].forEach.call(a, function(elem){
  var b = elem.getAttribute('href');
  var newHref = "http://www.domainname.com/index/" +  b.replace(/#/g, '') + "/get";
  elem.setAttribute("href", newHref);
  console.log(newHref);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery way:

```
items = $("a");

$(items).each(function(index, item){
    b = $(item).attr('href');
    c = b.replace("#", "");
    d = "http://www.domainname.com/index/" + c + "/get";
    //console.log(d); //just to check them out
    item.attr('href', d);
});
```